# MQTT with SSL and with enforced client certificate, When we renew the SLL certificate expiration date do we need to update the clients cert?

Tags: ssl, mqtt

We have some IOT MQTT clients connecting to a MQTT broker with SLL and enforcing the clients to have a matching cert to connect, dose that mean on yearly bases we need to update the cert in clients to match the updated Broker SSL? or it's not needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "valid from" and "valid until" dates are encoded into the certificate, so you will need to issue new certificates before the old one expires and find a way to deliver it to the actual device.

You can not just update a value "server side" and expect it to work.

Comment: Thanks, it will be less time consuming and less running around  to not enforce the IOT client to have a certificate and just accept the broker certificate if its issued by a trusted provider, plus authentication.

Comment: Using individual certificates provide a way to uniquely identify each device unlike using a username/password which can be copied between devices. They work best when paired with a secure element